# Calculating standard deviation on data stored in a cell array of cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, cell-array

I have a cell array `A` Mx3 in size where each entry contains a further cell-array Nx1 in size, for example when M=9 and N=5:

[image]

All data contained within in any given cell array is in vector format and of equal length. For example, `A{1,1}` contains 5 vectors 1x93 in size whilst `A{1,2}` contains 5 vectors 1x100 in size:

[image]

I wish to carry out this procedure on each of the 27 cells:

```
B = transpose(cell2mat(A{1,1}));
B = sort(B);
C = std(B,0,2);  %Calculate standard deviation
```

Ultimately, the desired outcome would be, for the above example, 27 columns (9x3) containing the standard deviation results (padded with 0 or NaNs to handle differing lengths) printed in the order `A{1,1}`, `A{1,2}`, `A{1,3}`, `A{2,1}`, `A{2,2}`, `A{2,3}` and so forth.

I can do this by wrapping the above code into a loop to iterate over each one of the 27 cells in the correct order however, I was wondering if there was a clever cellfun or more succinct method to accomplish this particularly without the use of a loop?

Comment: Having a bit of trouble understanding how this is supposed to work.  So is each element in `A` is a further cell array of 5 elements, where each element is a vector... and each vector has the same length?  Also, when you are calculating the standard deviation, what is the input into this function?  What exactly do you mean when you say "each point between the 5 samples"?

Comment: Updated OP to hopefully clarify the situation.

Comment: I'm not calculating STDEV for the vector as a whole but rather on a point by point basis. Five 1x93 vectors will produce STDEV results held in a single 1x93 vector. In other words, I want to know what the variation is between the 5 samples (which are duplicate simulations under identical conditions to one another) at each rank ordered position.

Comment: I got it.  I had to read the code in order to understand what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably realize that `cellfun` is essentially a glorified `for` loop over cells.  There's simply extra error checking and all that to ensure that the whole thing works.  In any case, yes it's possible to do what you're asking in a single `cellfun` call.  Note that I am simply going to apply the same logic as you would have in a `for` loop with `cellfun`.  Also note that because you're using cell arrays, you have no choice but to iterate over the entire master cell array.  However, what you'll want to do is pad each resulting column vector in each output in the final cell array so that they all share the same length.  We can do that with another two `cellfun` calls - one to determine the largest vector length and another to perform the padding operation.

Something like this could work:

```
% Step #1 - Sort the vectors in each cell array, then find row-wise std
B = cellfun(@(x) std(sort(cell2mat(x).'), 0, 2), A, 'un', 0);

% Step #2 - Determine the largest length vector and pad
sizes = cellfun(@numel, B);
B = cellfun(@(x) [x; nan(max(sizes(:)) - numel(x), 1)], B, 'un', 0);
```

The first line of code takes each element in `A`, converts each cell element into a `N x 5` column matrix (i.e. `cell2mat(x).'`), we then sort each column individually with `sort`, then take the standard deviation row-wise.  Because the output is ultimately a vector, we must make sure that the `'UniformOutput'` flag is 0, or `'un=0'`.  Once we complete the standard deviation calculation, we determine the total number of elements for each resulting column vector for all cell elements, determine the **largest** size then use another `cellfun` call to pad these vectors so they all match the same size.

To finally get your desired output, you need to transpose the cell array, then unroll the elements in column major order.  Remember that MATLAB accesses things in column major, so a common trick to get things in row-major (what you want) as opposed to column major is to first transpose, then unroll in column-major fashion to perform a row-major readout.  Doing this in one line is tricky, so you'll need to not only transpose the cell array, you must use `reshape` to ensure that the elements are read out in row major format, but then ensuring that the result is placed in a row of cells, then call `cell2mat` so you can piece these vectors together. The final result should be a 27 column matrix where we have pieced all of these vectors together in a single row-wise fashion:

```
C = cell2mat(reshape(B.', 1, []));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What would be a good way to then convert this into a 27-column matrix printed in the correct order? I'm only aware of doing this: `cell2mat((B(:).'))` but this prints it B{1,1}, B{2,1}, B{3,1} and so forth rather than across each row.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann Ah, you're very close.  You need to transpose the cell array, then unroll it like you're doing already.  Remember that MATLAB accesses things in column major, so a common trick to get things in row-major (what you want) as opposed to column major is to first transpose, then unroll.  Doing this in one line is tricky, so you'll need to use `reshape` to first transpose the cell array, then unroll the elements to be in the correct order. You'll also need to transpose this matrix again if you want 27 columns, as this would originally make 27 rows:  `cell2mat(reshape(B.', 1, [])).';`